# entity framework validateentity best practise

Tags: entity-framework, validation

ValidateEntity provides a place to add custom validation. However, it seems to me, putting validation logic for all types of entities in this method seems to violate srp. Is there a better way to implements this, preferably by putting this logic for each type of entity in its own class, and letting validateentity call this class in a generic way?

Comment: what is srp? please be clear

Comment: I think "Single responsibility principle"

Comment: yes, sorry, single responsibility principle